# Framework / Software documentation referals to S/O

Tags: discussion

I am looking around new systems lately and beginning to see something worryingly similar to this popping up...

"If you have any questions, post it on Stack Overflow and tag it with xyz".

Most of the places I see this, the systems have little or no documentation and are using S/O as a poor mans user manual.

Don't get me wrong, I really like the Singularity SCSS grid framework, its one of the few frameworks that say this and actually have reasonably good documentation.

But I still think that this is just a way for frameworks to get links to their systems for both SEO purposes, and to avoid having to do proper documentation.

Most such places I have seen this quote on actually have little or no documentation. Which effectively means SO will cease to be a Q&A site and start becoming a very poor excuse for proper documentation (no offense). I just don't think documenting frameworks or software systems was the intent of S/O.

So this new trend really worries me. Should / Could something be done about this or is it something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 3):

Some of the questions will be high-quality ones with value for multiple users. Those will be answered, visible and searchable.  Everybody wins. The existence or non-existence of good documentation elsewhere doesn't change the value of a well-written, well-answered SO question.

Some (many, probably) will be low-quality -- downvoted, closed, deleted.

I see no reason to expect this to change SO in any noticeable way.

Comment: That's a very fair point. Thanks for your answer. However if anyone has a website and makes blog posts, they can say - Any questions, post on stack overflow and tag it, in their answer they can link back to their site. Likewise with youtubers and many other sites. Free SEO and nobody at S/O would mind. Awesome.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers this was discussed many times: it more likely alienate people one redirects to SO because  it is *hard* to ask reasonable question that does not get -5 votes in one minute. Also it is hard to *properly* answer SO question with link to ones site without getting marked as spam...